# merging two output records to one row

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[Test]  @locid int as  begin
declare @Mns decimal , @dec decimal
select @dec= AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ))  FROM Transaction_tbl t WHERE Locid=@locid 
select HH=convert(decimal(10,1) ,@dec/60)  select @Mns=@dec%60
 select @dec=@dec/60   select mm=@Mns
  end
```

That is returning output in two recored

```
HH
29.1

mm
6
```

i want to get output in 1 row.expected out put like this:

```
HH           mm
29.1          6
```

how i can do that?

Comment: Are you shure you want to get 0.2 hh 12 min for @dec = 12 ? If not you should use `declare  @dec int`

Comment: consider changing procedure to have one select like in answer from @Devart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe put HH and mm in one select at the end:

```
    alter procedure [dbo].[Test]  @locid int as  begin
    declare @Mns decimal , @dec decimal
    select @dec= AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ))  FROM Transaction_tbl t WHERE Locid=@locid;
    -- select @Mns=@dec%60;
    -- select @dec=@dec/60;   
    select HH=convert(decimal(10,1) ,@dec/60), mm=@dec%60;
    end
```

Comment: this out put is getting in one row..but out put value is getting wrong

Comment: I comment out unnecessary :D

Comment: I commented out only this row(select @dec=@dec/60; ).Now working fine..thanks for your replay.

Comment: @user2603688 check if `@dec` is getting value you expected

Answer (score 3):

Solution without any additional variables -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
@locid INT
AS BEGIN

     SELECT 
            mm = [dec] % 60
          , HH = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), [dec] / 60)
     FROM (
          SELECT [dec] = AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)))
          FROM dbo.Transaction_tbl t
          WHERE Locid = @locid
     ) t

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select
   @Mns As Mns,
   @HH As HH
```

You can select anything, just separate them with commas

```
Select
   'John'           As MyName,
   5*20             As MyCalc,
   MONTH(GetDate()) AS ThisMonth,
   @SomeVariable    As SomeVariable
```

Output

```
MyName    MyCalc    ThisMonth    SomeVariable
-----------------------------------------------
John      100       7            0
```